# How to detect when app starts from pressing hardware button in Android WearOS and navigate to different compose screens?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch

I am developing a WearOS app using Jetpack compose and I have one activity and multiple composable screens.

I have a requirement to launch app to two different destinations.

1. **User click app icon** -> User will navigate to Home Screen.
2. **User double press the Home button ( User has customized the Home button from the watch to open the app)**  -> User will navigate to SOS screen.

When there is no any app instance in background or foreground, the above scenario works fine. This is my code for that ,

```
if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_MAIN && intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)) 
    {
        Screen.HomeScreen.route
    }
    else {
        Screen.SosScreen.route
    }
```

The problem is, when user double press the Home button(Hardware) when app is in background or foreground, it resumes the app so it can't handle using above method. How to do this in WearOS app ?. Any wearable API which I can achieve this?

Comment: Double press is to resume the activity, yes. You shouldn't be using it for anything but that.

Comment: @ianhanniballake my requirement is to fire a SOS alert when user double press by redirecting user to different screen. Any idea how to achieve it.

Comment: Create two launchers, one for the default screen and one for the the SOS screen, then the user set the SOS "app" to open when he double tap it